# change cells color in jTable when the value of cells is true java

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

when i insert data into jtable i test if the value of cells is true, how i can change the background color of this cell

here is my code :

```
private void getEtudians(){
    Etudiant e = new Etudiant();
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)jTable1.getModel();
    deleteTable(model);
    ArrayList<Vector> ETUDIANTS = e.getAllEtudiansNom(2);
    for (int i = 0; i <ETUDIANTS.size(); i++) {

         System.out.print(i);
         Vector v = new Vector();
         v.add(i+1);
         v.addAll(ETUDIANTS.get(i));
         model.addRow(v);

    }
    jTable1.setModel(model);

}
```

Comment: See the [editor/renderer concept for JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add component to focus it like :

```
    String[] header = { "ID", "Name", "Department" };

    String[][] datas = { { "0001", "Onur", "Java Developer" }, { "0002", "Umut", "Musical Ens" },
            { "0003", "Eymen", "Just Reader" }, { "0004", "Mustafa", "Worker" } };

    boolean isSelected = false;
    boolean hasFocus = false;

    JTable table = new JTable(datas, header);
    int rows = table.getRowCount();
    int cols = table.getColumnCount();
    Object color = (Color) Color.CYAN;
    table.setOpaque(false);
    table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    table.setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
    table.setBounds(30, 40, 200, 300);

    if (table.isCellSelected(rows, cols)) {
        isSelected = true;
    }
    Component comp = getTableCellRendererComponent(table, color, isSelected, hasFocus, rows, cols);
    if (rows == 1 && cols == 1)
        comp.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 255));
    JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(table);
    getContentPane().add(pane);

}

@Override
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object color, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
        int row, int column) {
    Color newColor = (Color) color;
    table.setBackground(newColor);

    if (isSelected) {

        table.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
    } else {

        table.getSelectionBackground();
    }
    // Discussed in the following section
    return null;
}
```